# css flexbox / tailwind 'simple' alignment not working as I expect

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm attempting to create a simple section with 4 sections - top left, bottom left, top right, and bottom right. I'm unable to do something seemingly very simple. That is, I want an element in the top right to be middle aligned (vertically) within its section and the element in the bottom right to be bottom aligned (vertically) in its section. I don't understand the reason the following doesn't work. Thanks.

```
<div class="w-full bg-white border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow">

  <div class="flex h-full">
    <div class=" w-2/3 border-r border-gray-500">

      <div class="bg-red-50 p-4">
        <div class="h-20">
          top left section
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bg-gray-50 p-4">
        bottom left section
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-1/3">
      <div class="bg-green-50 flex content-center p-4">
        <div class="block">
        <!-- I want this guy to be vertically middle aligned -->
          top right section
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bg-gray-50 flex content-end p-4">
        <div class="block">
          <!-- I want this guy to be vertically bottom aligned -->
          bottom right section
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

(edit: I was looking at the first search result for tailwind content-end class, it was the wrong one lol but the rest still stands)

So `align-items` for shared vertical alignment across multiple flex children or `align-self` to have different settings per child.  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-self
try using `align-self` instead and moving the flex class onto the parent div of both your sections e.g. the div with `.w-1/3`

Comment: thanks, 'Align Content' was the tailwind utility I was missing.